# Validate LMA/FMA Before Publishing To AppExchange

Tags: managed-package, deployment, appexchange, isv, lma

Is it possible to validate that your LMA/FMA code functions correctly before you ever upload a package to the AppExchange?

I have an existing, released managed package that I need to try using LMA/FMA to control access to features. I want to make sure that the capability of LMA meet our needs, but we're not ready for this to go live on the AppExchange yet.